# change and kenburn zoom web page background image by click on another div

Tags: javascript, css

i need to change and kenburn zoom, my web page background image by click  on another div.

Can you please tell me how to do that.

[check my coads here](http://jsfiddle.net/ramswarnak/NA3tH/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.box1').on('click', function () {

        $('.kenburns').addClass('zoom');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the css as

```
.kenburns.zoom {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2) rotate(0.1deg);
    -moz-transform: scale(2) rotate(0.1deg);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kMpC5/)

If your html markup is same as the fiddle then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.box1').on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent('.kenburns').addClass('zoom');
    });
});
```

You need to add the zoom transition to the `.kenburns` element, not to its descendent

Comment: when i put this coad to web page not only the image but all the items of page are zooming. but i need zoom with kenburn effect only background image.how to figure it out?

Comment: You probably want to use a normal image rather than a background-image. If you were to use a background-image you would need to manipulate the `background-position` and `background-size` properties.

Comment: in this demo, when click the box1, text on box1 also zooming, but i need zoom only background image not items on page. can you help with this please.....